# What is the difference between Task<> and IAsyncOperation<>

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, microsoft-metro

I am writing a metro app.

This works:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(new Uri("www.microsoft.com"));
```

This doesn't:

```
    var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("text.txt");
```

The first one returns a Task<>, the second one return an IAsyncOperation<>

What is the difference? Why are there two different types? How can I fix the second sample?

Comment: What do you mean, the second one doesn't work? What *does* it do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`IAsyncOperation` is a metro asynchronous operation. You can `await` an `IAsyncOperation`.

However, you can't use `IAsyncOperation` with `Task.WhenAll` or `Task.WhenAny`. To use `IAsyncOperation` instances with these methods, you should call the [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.astask?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) extension method (formerly `StartAsTask`) from `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`, as such:

```
var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var fileTask = folder.GetFileAsync("text.txt").AsTask();
```

Comment: What namespace is the StartAsTask() extension method defined?

Comment: `StartAsTask` has changed to [`AsTask`, which is in `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779747(v=vs.110).aspx).