# Testing IAsyncOperation using Task in c#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have been asigned to do unit testing of an metro application which has got lot of asynchronous functions (IAsyncOperation) in c#. How to unit test IAsyncOperation functions or can we use Task with IAsyncOperation functions for testing.If yes, please give me an example. Because IAsyncOperation works only in winRT and Task in normal c# for parallalism

Answer (score 3):

You can test methods returning `IAsyncOperation<T>` directly. Start with creating a new project based on the `UnitTestLibrary (Windows Store apps)` project template.

Assuming you want to test the following method:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IAsyncOperation<string> GetString()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You can call it from a test class as follows:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        Assert.AreEqual("result", await viewModel.GetString());
    }
}
```

Just make sure you use `async Task` instead of `void` in your test method signature.

Comment: Thanks Damir, it works but it does not show pass or fail test result in Test Explorer like the other normal synchronous tests.

Comment: @user1920851 That's strange. It works just fine for me. Does it happen to you for every test? Try creating a really simple asynchronous test just to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IAsyncOperation<T>.StartAsTask()` method to generate a `Task<T>` corresponding to the async operation.

This StackOverflow question may be helpful: [What is the difference between Task<> and IAsyncOperation<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034239/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-iasyncoperation)